# Converting a long list in a column into a new df

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, plot

I have a huge df with a list inside a column that I want to plot. The column looks is similar to this:

```
tracking_information
'438 673.4841918945312 1552924050927 ; 666 709.5 1552924050911 ; 344...'
'343 775.5 1552924084000 ; 460.4154052734375 669 1552924084020 ; 403...'
```

The first number is the x coordinate, the second y and the third the timestamp. The list has 1000s of entries for each row. 
I tried fitting it into an .array() but due to the formatting I was unable to do so. I also tried to convert it to int and then use pd.Series which also didn't result in anything but an error.

Ideally each row creates a new df with the headers x, y, timestamp and each value seperated in a row similar to this:

```
df2:
x, y, z
438, 673.4841918945312, 1552924050927 
666, 709.5, 1552924050911
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

Sample input:

```
import pandas as pd
df_inp = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["438 673.4841918945312 1552924050927 ; 666 709.5 1552924050911 ;", "438 673.4841918945312 1552924050927 ; 666 709.5 1552924050911 ;","343 775.5 1552924084000 ; 460.4154052734375 669 1552924084020 ;"]})
```

Output:

```
col1
0   438 673.4841918945312 1552924050927 ; 666 709....
1   438 673.4841918945312 1552924050927 ; 666 709....
2   343 775.5 1552924084000 ; 460.4154052734375 66...
```

Now try below to convert to DF format you want:

```
def expand_input(inp):
    return [x.strip().split(" ") for x in inp.split(";")]

pd.DataFrame([
    list_vars for x in df_inp["col1"].apply(expand_input).iteritems() for list_vars in x[1] if list_vars[0]
],  columns=["x","y","z"])
```

Output:

```
  x y    z
0   438 673.4841918945312   1552924050927
1   666 709.5   1552924050911
2   438 673.4841918945312   1552924050927
3   666 709.5   1552924050911
4   343 775.5   1552924084000
5   460.4154052734375   669 1552924084020
```

Answer (score 0):

1> create three separate list
2>Iterate over your data frame row and column and (as you mentioned your cell is the list) then iterate over list divide its value into the list created above
3>Now plot the graph.
comment for more help, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you want

```
test = ['438;666;344','asd;aweq;ascx']
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
splittedDf=df[0].str.split(' ')
arr = []
for i in range(len(splittedDf)):
   arr.append(splittedDf[i])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print(new_df)
```